# Curl execution in python failed

Tags: python-3.x, perl, subprocess

I wanted to download files for around 300 item. An example is below:

```
curl 'http://genome.jgi.doe.gov/ext-api/downloads/get-directory?organism=Absrep1' -b cookies > Absrep1.xml
```

This opens the page and downloads the content and stores it as xml file in my end

I tried to do a batch script in perl with system command, like

```
system('curl 'http://genome.jgi.doe.gov/ext-api/downloads/get-directory?organism=Absrep1'
-b cookies > Absrep1.xml');
```

But, it did not work. There was syntax error, which I guess is due to single quotes.

I tried with python,

```
import subprocess
bash_com = 'curl "http://genome.jgi.doe.gov/ext-api/downloads/get-directory?organism=Absrep1" '
subprocess.Popen(bash_com)
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bash_com])
```

It did not work. I get the error, File does not exist. Even if it works, how can I include the

> -b cookies > Absrep1.xml'

part in it?

Please help. Thanks in Advance,

AP

Comment: I just found out, it is easier with os.system("curl 'http://genome.jgi.doe.gov/ext-api/downloads/get-directory?organism=Absrep1' -b cookies > Absrep1.xml")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perl, you should be able to use this:

`system(q{curl 'http://genome.jgi.doe.gov/ext-api/downloads/get-directory?organism=Absrep1' -b cookies > Absrep1.xml});`

However, you might be better off using [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) or possibly even [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny)(unless you need the cookies) instead of shelling out. For more advanced uses, there is also [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is almost certainly down to the quotes in the system call:

`system('curl 'http://genome.jgi.doe.gov/ext-api/downloads/get-directory?organism=Absrep1' -b cookies > Absrep1.xml');`

The single quotes either need to be escaped or alternative parentheses can be used such as double quotes or custom parentheses with q or qq, eg:

`system(q{curl 'http://genome.jgi.doe.gov/ext-api/downloads/get-directory?organism=Absrep1' -b cookies > Absrep1.xml});`

It's hard to tell from the context given, but wrapping the curl call in perl or python would likely be a less than optimal approach. Perl has LWP, Python has requests, and the bash shell is already well equipped to run simple batch jobs. It might be best to stick to a single interpreter unless there's a good reason not to.